# Angular: NX mono repo - Dynamic Module federation - Is it possible for a remote module to exposes a route to another remote module

Tags: angular, angular-module-federation, nx-monorepo

There is my issue :

I'm currently busy to discover angular app NX mono repo with dynamic module federation.

This is my structure :

- **shellApp** => Shell
- **remote-1** => Remote MF
- **remote-2** => Remote MF

I would like to make something like that:

- Url **/citizen** gives me remote-1 MF
- Url **/citizen/xxx** gives me remote-2 MF (and remote-1 of course )

There is my current routing config from shellApp :

export const appRoutes: Route[] = [

```
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'citizen',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'citizen',
        loadChildren: () =>loadRemoteModule('remote-1', './Module').then((m) => m.RemoteEntryModule),
      },
```

This works perfectlly.

But when I try to make the same config in **my remote-1** to have this kind of url (see bellow)

**remote-entry/entry.routes.ts** from remote-1 MF

```
    {
        path: 'xxx',
        loadChildren: () =>loadRemoteModule('remote-2', './Module').then((m) => m.RemoteEntryModule),
    }
```

The consoles gives me following error.

core.mjs:10183 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: **Call setRemoteDefinitions or setRemoteUrlResolver to allow Dynamic Federation to find the remote apps correctly.
Error: Call setRemoteDefinitions or setRemoteUrlResolver to allow Dynamic Federation to find the remote apps correctly.**
at nx-angular-mf.mjs:30:15

I still checked that my remote-2 config is correct by doing the following test in Shell and it works:

```
    {
        path: 'xxx',
        loadChildren: () =>
            loadRemoteModule('remote-2', './Module').then((m) => m.RemoteEntryModule),
    },
```

Is it possible for a remote app to use in his routing another remote app ?

Answer (score 0):

> Url /citizen/xxx gives me remote-2 MF

will it work if the route is also defined in the shell app?

```
const appRoutes: Route[] = [
  ...
  {
    path: 'citizen',
    loadChildren: () =>loadRemoteModule('remote-1', './Module').then((m) => m.RemoteEntryModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'citizen/xxx',
    loadChildren: () =>loadRemoteModule('remote-2', './Module').then((m) => m.RemoteEntryModule),
  },
]
```